# Creating JSON in java using org.json

Tags: java, json, org.json

I am trying to create a json string in java using org.json library and following is the code snippet.

```
JSONArray jSONArray = new JSONArray();
JSONObject jSONObject = new JSONObject();
jSONObject.accumulate("test", jSONArray);
System.out.println(jSONObject.toString());
```

I expected it to print

```
{"test":[]}
```

while it prints

```
{"test":[[]]}
```

Comment: Here's a short video that demonstrates creating a JSONObject using org.json. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-qEpxIARKxE

Answer (score 10, accepted):

instead of using `accumulate` use `put` this way it won;t add it to a pre-existing (or create and add) JSONArray, but add it as a key to the JSONObject like this:

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("test", array);
System.out.println(obj.toString());
```

and now it'll print `{"test":[]}`

Answer (score 4):

That is because in the `accumulate` method,

```
Object object = this.opt(key); //gets the key value. Null in your case.
if (object == null) {
    this.put(key,
        value instanceof JSONArray ? new JSONArray().put(value) : value);
}
```

This is as per the API which clearly says (for the `accumulate` method) -

> Accumulate values under a key. It is similar to the put method except
>   that if there is already an object stored under the key then a
>   JSONArray is stored under the key to hold all of the accumulated
>   values. If there is already a JSONArray, then the new value is
>   appended to it. In contrast, the put method replaces the previous
>   value. If only one value is accumulated that is not a JSONArray, then
>   the result will be the same as using put. But if multiple values are
>   accumulated, then the result will be like append.

You can use `put()` as mentioned in the other answer, for your desired result.